c++ で auto&& [x,y,z]{arr}; という書式でなぜarrの要素と変数x,y,zが紐づくのか
AtCoder Beginner Contest 365 D - AtCoder Janken 3の解説に次のようなコードがありました．

array<unsigned, 3> dp{};
auto&& [rock, scissors, paper]{dp};


解説のコードでこれら三つの変数rock, scissors, paperの挙動を追ってみると，dpの値を変更すると三つの変数の値も変更されておりました．auto&&で参照が作られることはわかるのですが，配列dpの各要素とこれら三つの変数がなぜ紐づけられるのかよくわかりませんでした．
auto&& [rock, scissors, paper]{dp};

このような変数の割り付けの方法がweb上の解説を見ても見当たらなかったので，どなたかご存知の方お教えくださいませ．

auto&& [rock, scissors, paper]{dp};は例えば　auto&& x{100}という初期化子と同じ書式なのでしょうか．
この書式は配列特有なものなのでしょうか．

最終的にはそういうものだからということなのでしょうが，何か学ぶべき事項や参考になるものがあればご教示いただけますと幸いです．

C++17 で導入された構造化束縛ですね。配列の他にも構造体のメンバなどで複数の変数を一度に初期化することができます。

ありがとうございました！理解できました！
